# Workfront/Attask: Retrieving "workUnit" from Task or Assignment returns http-500

Tags: attask, workfront-api

For objects "Assignment" and "Task" the field "workUnit" is documented in the Workfront-Apiexplorer: https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/api-explorer/ (sry, i cannot deeplink to a certain object in the documentation). I am using version 4.0.
But when executing https://.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v4.0/ASSGN/search?sessionID=SOMESESSIONID&method=GET&assignedTo:lastName=SOMELASTNAME&fields=workRequired,avgWorkPerDay,task,task%3AdurationUnit,assignedTo,project,role,workUnit 
i get 500 as returncode.
Task:durationUnit is working.

Is this a bug in the documentation or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The cause seems to be from the workUnit field in the fields section. This is a bug since it is contained both in the metadata for ASSGN and in the developers website.

Comment: Do you know where i can file that bug? At the Workfront-homepage it is all directed to stackoverflow, so will someone create a bug at Workfront because of my question, or do i have to do something else?

Comment: A bug can be logged by going online at  helpdesk.attask.com or by calling 1-844-306-HELP (4357) or you can email customercare@workfront.com